# "Структура данных «Массив» имеет фиксированный размер". Это всегда так?

Tags: массивы, структуры-данных, динамические-массивы

[В статье про структуру данных](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-1-introduction/) `связанный список`, автор пишет про недостатки `массива`:

> 1) The size of the arrays is fixed: So we must know the upper limit on
>   the number of elements in advance...

и тут же во втором пункте, *как мне кажется*, он это опровергает

> 2) Inserting a new element in an array of elements is expensive...

Т.е. сначала говорится, что массив – это фиксированный набор данных, а затем говорится о **добавлении**. Как это понимать или автор имеет ввиду уже разновидность массива – `динамический массив`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Важно различать **элемент** и **место под элемент**. Массив не всегда весь заполнен, но даже незаполненная часть занимает память<sup>1</sup>. Фиксировано в массиве число **мест**. Элементов в массиве ненулевой длины может не быть.

Из-за особенностей хранимого типа может быть невозможно иметь в массиве ячейку без значения, но это лишь техническая деталь — если значение не имеет смысла, для алгоритма его всё равно что нет. И следить за такой ситуацией можно, храня где-то неподалёку число "полезных элементов", если вы заполняете массив последовательно от начала (что бывает не всегда).

---

Во втором пункте говорится о дороговизне **вставки элемента в произвольное место** с сохранением существующих элементов массива и порядка их следования<sup>2</sup>.

Чтобы её осуществить когда место занято, нужно все элементы, начиная с запрашиваемого места и вверх по индексам до конца заполненной части массива, переместить на одно место вперёд. Худший случай — вставка в начало, когда необходимо сдвинуть вперёд всю заполненную часть массива.

Для сравнения, для вставки элемента в связный список (с тем же требованием сохранить порядок) необходимо лишь создать запись списка с элементом и прописать её в указывающего на неё соседа (или двух, если список двусвязаный). Такая богатая на переходы по ссылкам структура заметно замедляет обход, но в некоторых узких нишах она удобна.

Нет, динамические массивы тут ни при чём.

---

<sup>1</sup> если не используется трюков вроде разрежения, но с ними это уже не тот примитивный массив, о котором речь

<sup>2</sup> в пределах двух частей, на которые вставляемный элемент этот массив разделяет

Comment: Я думал элемент в массив можно добавлять только в конец или это уже зависит от спецификации языка программирования? Мой язык `C#`.

Comment: @adamshakhabov что вы понимаете под "добавлением"? Запись в ранее неиспользуемую ячейку (место под элемент) массива полезного значения? Нет, необязательно в конец, это может быть любая ячейка в границах массива. А если вы о гарантированном сохранении элемента в массив, даже в условиях когда он заполнен, то обычный массив на это неспособен в принципе, поскольку возможности самопроизвольно расширяться не имеет. Вот.

Comment: Шарп, как "безопасный язык", подозреваю, не допускает работы с неинициализированной памятью (где может быть что угодно при первом обращении), и все ячейки массива в нём изначально заполнены значениями по умолчанию. В этом контексте "добавление элемента" в него невозможно, только перезапись "добавляемым элементом" одного из этих значений.